# Open3やDaemonsを使って外部のRubyスクリプトを実行する際に、実行に必要なgemをロードできるようにしたい

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, bundler

つまってしまったので教えてください。
Rais,Rubyは初めて書いているので、見当違いのことをしているかもしれません。

RailsからOpen3のcapture3メソッドを実行してデーモンを立ち上げたいのですが、「cannot load such file」となってしまいました。

```
# top_controller.rb(Railsからの呼び出し処理)

def daemon_start
    cmd = "/bin/app start;"
    out, err, status = Open3.capture3(cmd)
    p out               
    p err              
    p status.exitstatus

    redirect_to root_path
end
```

```
# app(呼び出されるapp)

#!/usr/bin/env ruby
require 'bundler/setup'
require 'daemons'
require 'pathname'

base_dir = Pathname('../../').expand_path(__FILE__)
Daemons.run(
  base_dir.join('bin/bot'),
  app_name: 'bot',
  dir_mode: :normal,
  dir: base_dir.join('tmp'),
  log_dir: base_dir.join('log'),
  log_output: true
)
```

```
#表示内容(err)

"bin/app:3:in `require': cannot load such file -- daemons (LoadError)\n\tfrom bin/app:3:i"
```

以下、試してみたことです。

- appをターミナルから実行
  →問題なく起動します。
- ruby -Iでgemのパスを追加
  cmdを
  cmd = "ruby -I /Users/owner/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/daemons-1.2.3/lib /bin/app start;"
  と変えたところ、エラーは出なくなります。
  (-Iで/Users/owner/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/を渡すと最初のエラーと変わらずです)
- requireしているパスを絶対パスに変更
  同じ様に、エラーは出なくなります。
- app内で$LOAD_PATH.unshiftする
  $LOAD_PATH.unshift('/Users/owner/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/daemons-   1.2.3/lib')
  同じ様に、エラーは出なくなります。
  ただ、上2つもそうなのですが、appから呼ばれるbotの中でrequireしているgemが見つからないとなってしまいます。

```
#そのときのエラー表示内容
(botがrequireしているretryableの中でrequireしているファイルが見つからない)

/Users/owner/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/retryable-2.0.2/lib/retryable.rb:1:in `require': cannot load such file -- retryable/version (LoadError)
```

【質問】
appをターミナルから実行すれば正常に動いているので、パスが通ってないことが問題と考えています。
使用するgemに上で試したことと同じ対応をすべてのgemにすればなんとかなるのかもしれませんですが、それなりの数があるため避けたいです。
もっといい方法でパスを通す方法があるでしょうか？
なんでもいいので教えていただきたいです。
足りない情報があれば追記します。
よろしくお願いします。

【環境】
Rails:4.1
Ruby:2.2.0(Railsで使用)
Ruby:2.2.0(appで使用)

Answer (score 1):

Rails側でappの実行に必要となるgemをbundle installしたら、とりあえず起動できました。
ですが、もっといい方法があるかもしれないので、引き続き回答をお待ちしています。

Answer (score 1):

### 原因

```
## /bin/app の中の ##
require 'bundler/setup'
```

は何をやるかというと、カレントディレクトリから上に登っていって、最初に見つけた Gemfile の情報を利用して gem を LOAD_PATH に設定します。さらにはその際に、グローバルでインストールされている gem の load_path 情報は、 bundler が設定するものと被ってはいけないので、 [`clean_load_path`](https://github.com/bundler/bundler/blob/0c5d3b8c1f391aa5175321675ecd91ee6a1f231b/lib/bundler/shared_helpers.rb#L330) でもってそれらを無視する挙動になっている様子です。なので、 bundler を利用する場合は、それが読み込む Gemfile に、すべての依存 gem を記述しなければ、正しく動作しなさそうです。

### 今回何が起こったかを簡単にまとめると

1. Rails のプロセスから `Open3` が呼ばれる (pwd はおそらく rails の root) その際、実行されたコマンドは pwd を rails から引き継ぐ。
2. `bin/app` の `require 'bundler/setup'` の中で、 Gemfile の探索が行われる
3. Rails 自身の Gemfile が発見される
4. Rails の Gemfile が指定される gem たちでもって、 `LOAD_PATH` は設定されるが、そこには `daemon` などは含まれていない

### 取り得る対応

おそらく、 daemon やら app やらは rails とは独自に開発されている ruby のアプリケーションなのだと思います。 rails とは独自であるならば、 Gemfile をそれ用に用意して、ひとつのプロジェクトとして設定しましょう。そして、 `Open3` を実行する際に、 app の Gemfile が利用されるようにしましょう。

例えば次のように実行できるようにしたり:

```
# top_controller.rb の中で
cmd = 'cd /path/to/app/dir && bundle exec bin/app'
Open3.capture3 cmd
# ...
```

もしくは、利用したい Gemfile を明示的に指定したりなど

```
# app (呼び出される app)
ENV['BUNDLE_GEMFILE'] = File.expand_path('../Gemfile', __dir__)
# => (app ファイルがあるディレクトリからの相対パスでもって Gemfile を指定)
```

また、 daemon のスクリプトまで含めて rails プロジェクトの管理下に入れてしまう、というのも手の一つではあります。